# PHP mail with attachment, attachment is sent but with no body text

Tags: php, email, attachment

When I send the email, the email is sent with only attachment and the        message part does not appear. The preview say no text body. What went wrong? The code is provided below:

```
  <?php
  include 'header.php';
  if(isset($_POST['bookingsubmit']))
  {
    //print_r($_POST); 
    $to = "dungeonr977@gmail.com"; 
    $from = $_POST['email']; 
    $first_name = $_POST['fName'];
    $last_name = $_POST['lName'];
    $mobile= $_POST['mobile'];
    $airline= $_POST['airline'];
    $subject = "Flight Change Request";

    $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];  
    $temp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];  
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type']; 

    $base = basename($file_name);
    $extension = substr($base, strrpos($base, ".")-1);
    $file = $temp_name;
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)));
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));  //unique identifier

    $message = "Mr/Mrs/Ms ".$first_name." ".$last_name." wrote the following:"."\r\n".$_POST['message'];  

    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
    $headers .= "From:" . $from;
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion()."\r\n";        
    //$headers .= "--".$uid."\r\n";        
    $headers .= "Content-Type: ".$file_type."; name=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
    $headers .= $content; 
    //$headers2 = "From:" . $to;

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: wrote the following:"."\r\n"  remove . after following" and make string as following: \r\n"

Comment: Thanks. But still the email is sent without body, just the attachment only.

Comment: might be due to the line breaks you are using.

Comment: $message is the body part

Comment: Do not use $_POST['message'] in message . First get it in variable then use that variable

Comment: The `Content-Type:` in the global mail header says that you only have an attachment. `$content` doesn't belong in the headers then, but should be the message. If confused about how to construct MIME messages, use an established library (PEAR Mail, SwiftMailer, PHPMailer).

Comment: @mario thank you mario. How do i declare both text and attachment in Content-Type? if I include the content type in body, the body text appears but the attachment appear as random encrypted long text.

Comment: Investigate `multipart/mixed`, RFC2045, RFC2046 etc.